# Saving Outlook Message Files (.msg) including attachments in Python?

Tags: python, email, outlook, email-attachments, office-automation

I need to save Outlook-Mails with the attachments in the msg-file in Python. Currently working with `win32com.client` I use: `message.SaveAs(path + name)` which gives me a nice .msg file, but that does not include attachments (if attachments existent). Attached files are visible using `message.Attachments.Count` and `message.Attachments`, but how can I create a .msg-file with the attachments included to store as one file which works when messages are exported straight from Outlook?

Comment: `MailItem.SaveAs(.., olMsg)` does save the attachments inside the MSG file. Is this not what you are seeing?

Comment: I noticed that, but it  does not seem to work for all attachments. Attached messages do not work...

Comment: What are those messages? What are the attachment types? MSG format is full fidelity - it saves all MAPI properties (except for store specific one, such as entry id).

Comment: can you post  your current code?

Answer (score 0):

> how can I create a .msg-file with the attachments included to store as one file which works when messages are exported straight from Outlook?

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that. Potentially, the best that you could do, is save the attached files along with your mail items (msg). Use the [Attachment.SaveAsFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.saveasfile) method which saves the attachment to the specified path.

Comment: If your are going to answer your own question, I suggest including a reference as to how you arrived at your conclusion.

Comment: Where is my question? :)

Comment: omg my apologies!!! I completely misread the OP as being you instead of Ulrich. My mistake. Sorry about that.